# ExtJS Cannot read property 'stopEvent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, extjs

Im using ExtJS 3.3 and i have a combobox, what im trying to do is prevent the click action on certain items in the combobox.

The code im using is as follows;

```
listeners: {
    beforeselect: function(combo, record, index, e) {
        if(record.json[3] === false) {
            e.stopEvent();
        }
    }
},
```

It actually works, preventing a user from clicking an item, but the problem is that it also causing an error, as follows;

```
Cannot read property 'stopEvent' of undefined
```

If anyone has managed to get this going without causing an error message, that would be awesome if you could share it.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the docs? [They state the `beforeselect` event doesn't have four parameters.](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-beforeselect)

[To prevent the selection, as per the same docs:](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-beforeselect)

> Return false to cancel the selection.

So to summarize:

```
listeners: {
    beforeselect: function(combo, record, index) {
        if(record.json[3] === false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
},
```